# How to register Spring Batch Application in spring cloud data flow?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-batch-admin

I am trying to register Spring bath project jar file in spring cloud data flow. I am pretty new to spring cloud data flow. Please help me step by step process to register Spring batch Job in spring cloud data flow.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few [examples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_task_batch) in the [SCDF-samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples) repo.

Also, we spend cycles writing the documentation, so please make sure to review the reference guide; in particular the [task/batch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-task) sections could be useful.